# Works $(this) after $.post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Can I use `$(this).parentsUntil()...` after a `$.post?`
I need to remember what select element from the DOM changed and then append the information collected from my PHP to next select.

```
//OPTION SELECTED
$('body').on('change','.provincias, .partidos', function(e) {
    var idSelect = $(this).attr('id');

    var dataSelect = $(this).select2('data');
    var value = dataSelect.id;

    $.post('php/select/script.php', {id:idSelect, id_provincia:value, id_partido:value } , function(respuesta) {
        data = JSON.parse(respuesta);
        if(data.control == 0){
            alert(data.error)
            window.location.replace(data.url);
        }else{
            if(idSelect == data.thisSelect){
                for(var u=0; u<data.array1.length; u++){
                    $(this).parentsUntil('.formRow').next().children(data.nextSelect).append('<option value="' + data.array1[u].id + '">' + data.array1[u].nombre + '</option>');
                }
            }else if(idSelect == data.thisSelect){
                for(var t=0; t<data.array1.length; t++){
                    $(this).parentsUntil('.formRow').next().children('".' + data.nextSelect +'."').append('<option value="' + data.array1[u].id + '">' + data.array1[u].nombre + '</option>');
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution is to define another variable to hold the value of `this`, e.g. `self`, or in this case, you might want to call it `target`:

```
...
var target = this;
$.post('php/select/script.php', {id:idSelect, id_provincia:value, id_partido:value } , function(respuesta) {
    // Use target here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just save the `$(this)` in a variable.

```
$('body').on('change','.provincias, .partidos', function(e) {
var el = $(this);

...

el.parentsUntil('.formRow').next().children(data.nextSelect).append('<option value="' + data.array1[u].id + '">' + data.array1[u].nombre + '</option>');
```